# In an Entity Relationship Diagram how do you deal with Null data?

Tags: sql, attributes, entity, entity-relationship, visio

I'm making an ER diagram for a blogging website. Under the 'Comments' entity I have attributes Name,Email (P key), Content and Date/time stamp.

The website allows anonymous users to post so they won't have a Name/ Email.

Do I just add Null- Name/ Null- Email as attributes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I learned ERDs you have your 'Comments' entity with the attributes. When listing the attributes you can also include metadata about them - datatype, allows nulls, etc. I think you can list 'allows nulls' beside the attributes.

However, if 'Email' is your primary key, you can't have a null value for that attribute. You could assign each commenter a UserID and use that to maintain referential integrity if you want to keep email and name private info.

Comment: So are you saying instead of just 'Email' attribute it should be 'Email (allow null)' ?

Comment: I have only seen datatypes listed beside attributes in ERDs. I don't think allowing null or not is in the scope of making an ERD so I would leave it as Email. If Email is your primary key though, you do need to indicate that in that Entity. I think most people would put 'PK - Email'. This implies that the field can't contain null values though, which it can't.